About an application of UBP to the Fourier restriction
The Fourier restriction question :
Is it possible to restrict the Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ of a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $1\leq p\leq 2$ to the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ as a function in $L^q(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$ for some $1\leq q\leq\infty$?
I understand the above question. In Muscalu and Schlag's book "Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis - Vol 1", it is written that the above question is equivalent to the following estimate with the same $p$ and $q$ by the $\textbf{Uniform Boundedness Principle}$.
$$ \left\lVert \widehat{f} \right\rVert_{L^q(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})}\lesssim\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}\text{ }\text{ for all }\text{ }f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d) $$
I am not able to see the connection here. By the Uniform Boundedness Principle, how the above question is equivalent to the above estimate?

I'm not sure about BUP but the closed graph theorem should work here
